# How do I override the constructor of a PHP class?

Tags: php, oop

Here is my code. I am not experienced, so please tell me the answer in simple words.

```
<?php
function println($message) {
    echo "\n".$message;
}
```

println is essentialy echo but with a \n before the message. I am simply used to Python 3, but can't use print().

```
class Car {
    public function __construct($name) {
    //If the constructor is that of a car, it will be said that a car was made.

        println("Car made!");
        $this->distance_drived = 0;
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    function introductory() {
        return "This car is called ".$this->name.".";
    }
}

class Battery {
    function __construct($max_capacity, $current_capacity) {
        echo "Constructed!";
        $this->max_capacity = $max_capacity;
        $this->current_capacity = $current_capacity;
    }
    function fill($amount) {
        if ($amount + $this->current_capacity >= $this->max_capacity) {
            $this->fill_full();
        } else {
            $this->current_capacity += $amount;
        }
    }
    function fill_full() {
        $this->current_capacity = $this->max_capacity;
    }
    function use_power($amount) {
        if ($amount + $this->current_capacity >= $this->max_capacity) {
            return $this->current_capacity;
            $this->current_capacity = 0;
        } else {
            $this->current_capacity -= $amount;
            return $amount;
        }
    }
    function check_percentage() {
        return ($this->current_capacity / $this->max_capacity) * 100;
    }
}

class ElectricCar extends Car {
    public function __construct($name, $max_capacity, $current_capacity, $power_per_km) {
        println("Electric car made!");

        //If the constructor is that of an electric car, it will be said that a car was made.

        $this->distance_drived = 0;
        $this->name = $name;
        println($max_capacity);
        $this->battery = new Battery($max_capacity, $current_capacity);
    }
    public function move($km) {
        $power_required = $km * $this->power_per_km;
        $used = $battery->use_power($power_required);
        $this->distance_drived += $used / $this->power_per_km;
    }
}

$toyota = new Car("Toyota 2017");
println($toyota->name);
println($toyota->introductory());
$tesla = new Car("Tesla Model S", 1000, 750, 5);
println($tesla->introductory());
println("Capacity is ".$tesla->battery->max_capacity);

?>
```

My main problem is that the message remains the Car's message in the ElectricCar, therefore the __construct() did not change.

Comment: Try `$tesla = new ElectricCar("Tesla Model S", 1000, 750, 5);` then at least you will be using the correct class to instantiate the `$tesla` object

Comment: I suggest we close this as a TYPO

Answer (score 5):

Actually you are already overriding the parent constructor just writing a new constructor in the child class. When you don't rewrite the constructor, then the parent one is called.

From your code I can see you are creating Tesla as a Car, not as ElectricCar, that's why you get the Car message instead of the ElectricCar message.

FYI When you want your child class constructor to extend the parent class constructor, what you have to do is to call the parent constructor this way

```
parent::__construct();
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is in this line:

```
$tesla = new Car("Tesla Model S", 1000, 750, 5);
```

You never attempted to create an `ElectricCar`.  Change that line to

```
$tesla = new ElectricCar("Tesla Model S", 1000, 750, 5);
```

and everything should work as you expected.